# Scale Flash desktop app to iPhone/Android phone size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I have several games that were built 800*600 and need to convert them to run on the iPhone.

Are there any "easy" frameworks to convert the application without having to create all new images for Flash/AS3?

I was reading about starling but I don't see any way to easily convert our application witout rewriting a lot of it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: http://goo.gl/Xddcml
  ... Short of flat-out up-scaling, I'm pretty sure you'll need to update your assets if you want it to look decent.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your existing games. If they use a lot of vector graphics and full screen animation, performance will become an issue. But if you use a lot of bitmaps already, and not much animation, you might get away with just porting your games to AIR.

Flash CC has options to export assets to Bitmaps even if they were created using vectors ("Export as Bitmap").

You can optimize performance by using `cacheAsBitmap` on certain graphics (also look at `cacheAsBitmapMatrix`) but there you will enter rewrite territory.

Comment: We don't have a lot of animation and we use bitmaps mostly.